# How to add in Blazor on Grid a vertical scroll handler?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor

How to add a handler for the vertical scroll to the grid using Blazer or js scripts to load data into the grid?
Just Radzen Grid does not support this functionality.

```
<RadzenGrid @onscroll="OnScroll" AllowFiltering="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" style="height: 800px; overflow-y: scroll; position:fixed;" FilterDelay="800" ColumnWidth="200px">
        </RadzenGrid>
    @code {
    async Task OnScroll()
    {
        MyItems = await dbContext.MyItems.Take((count += 20)).ToListAsync();
        count = MyItems.Count();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a perfect solution. I use Material Design components. There are many useful features that are easy to use:
https://www.matblazor.com/
and scrolled one of them:
https://www.matblazor.com/VirtualScroll

Comment: The question is for Radzen not MatBlazor, which is not a good library in my opionion